# Can't enter loop with int but only using final int

Tags: java, arrays

I've created this class in a separate file and the program runs. The questions I have is the for a loop. Currently, I'm using a final int. I wanted to input a variable for 
ol < MAX_R

```
    } // End input loop

    // Added feature that is not part of grading
    System.out.print("Press enter to see results: ");
    try {
        System.in.read();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: It sounds like you've shown the code that *does* work rather than the code that *doesn't* work. Please show the code that's actually causing a problem.

Comment: java arrays are 0 based, you should replace for (int loopControl = 1; with for (int loopControl = 0;

Comment: where were you trying to read that value for MAX_ROUNDS?

Comment: What you are doing and when it is not working , what kind of modification you have done with this code? Show us that code which is not working.

Comment: My thought is it's because you declared the array before you got a value for `MAX_ROUNDS`, but without the non-working code it's impossible to say for sure.

Comment: This won't compile. You are using a local variable before declaring it (`MAX_ROUNDS`).

Comment: @mhvelplund it's `final` variable and there is difference

Comment: @DM `final` variables assigned at compile time, so if you look at the `byte code` you will see `double roundScores[] = new double[5];` and there is no error here

Comment: @jibrahim that doesn't make any difference? The only way this would work, is if the MAX_ROUNDS var was also a member var of the class or a static import from another class. My point is, the snippet above is incomplete.

Comment: Local final vars are not assigned at compile time?! You can set a final var to the result of method call.

Comment: Updated to the non working code. Only difference is instead of using MAX_ROUNDS I am using maxRounds and inputting the variable before the for loop instead of already declaring a final int in the declarations.

Comment: did not noticed that it was inside method and forgot that it must be also `static`, so you are right. Sorry for inconvenience!

Comment: Anyone that knows why I can't input?

Comment: Instead of moreRounds beinf static like before using a final int. I want for the user to be able to enter how ever many rounds they want to before the for loop.

Comment: but wheni ts entered by the user before the for loop instead of using final int, it throws exception with the array out of bounds after the user enters the first score.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think that author wants to read round scores for input stream and calculate an average. This is pretty simple, I think. First, you have to split your method into required logical parts: read data from stream, data processing, output data (to make your code simple and clear).

`Java` is **not** a `C++`. Here you can define array size wherever you like, as well as using user's input at runtime (`Java` does not require to know size of array at compile time).

```
public class Foo {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        double[] scores = readRoundScores();
        double avg = calcAverageScore(scores);

        System.out.println("\nAverage score: " + avg);
    }

    private static double[] readRoundScores() {
        try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            System.out.println("Enter total rounds: ");
            double[] scores = new double[scan.nextInt()];

            for (int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
                System.out.printf("Enter your round %d score: ", i + 1);
                scores[i] = scan.nextDouble();
            }

            return scores;
        }
    }

    private static double calcAverageScore(double... scores) {
        double sum = 0;

        for (double score : scores)
            sum += score;

        return sum / scores.length;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why did you wrapped `Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)` in `try`? Does it throw any `exception`?

Comment: Yes it is. Moreover, Scanner should be closed after usage and it implements Autoclosable.

Comment: To get advantage of `AutoCloseable` interface, that will close the `scanner` to avoid source leak, to read about https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html